# Qt XmlHttpRequest inappropriately modifies Content-type request header value by itself

Tags: qt, xmlhttprequest, qml, dropbox-api

I am trying to upload a file to Dropbox using XmlHttpRequest, in a QML application. I am getting the following error:

> Error in call to API function "files/upload": Bad HTTP "Content-Type"
>   header: "application/octet-stream;charset=UTF-8".  Expecting one of
>   "application/octet-stream", "text/plain; charset=dropbox-cors-hack".

I seems that no matter which value I set to the Content-Type request header, it always adds

> ;charset=UTF-8

to the end.

My test data is simply a string, of which I would like a text file be generated to the user's dropbox folder.

> request.send("TestString abcdefg")

How to deal with this issue?

Edit, with regards to the duplicate suspicion:
This is a similar issue, however, this particular case, if it can be addressed at all, needs to be addressed within the capabilities of Qt, on the QML javascript side, which has a set of different capabilities than javascript programming for the web, as it is a custom js engine, as far as I understand.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Dropbox v2 API from Browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33902289/using-dropbox-v2-api-from-browser)